# Initialize list variable as empty within Robot Framework ***Variables*** section

Tags: list, variables, initialization, robotframework

I would like to define a list variable which is empty initially:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
@{customers}=  []    # how to do this the right way? I expect an empty list.
    
*** Test Cases ***
Create Customers
    Add New Customer
    Add New Customer
    Log to console  ${customers}
    # results in:  ['[]', {'name': 'Ben', 'id': '123'}, {'name': 'Ben', 'id': '123'}]     

*** Keywords ***
Add New Customer
    ${customer}=  Create Dictionary  name=Ben  id=123
    Append To List  ${customers}  ${customer}
```

Regardless I know I could initialize @{customers} within testcase with 'Create List' I'm confused why the list has '[]' as first element. How I could initialize a list as empty in Variables section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built in variable `${EMPTY}` to explicitly init something to empty. You won't have a warning with it.

This one could be passed to keywords directly as well. For more check the User Guide, [Space and empty variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#space-and-empty-variables).

Answer (score 3):

For Robot, it's enough to do this:

```
*** Variables ***
@{customers}=
```

when you use `@`, Robot knows you're creating a list, and there's nothing on the right side, so it will be empty. And `=` is optional, so you could also type:

```
*** Variables ***
@{customers}
```

If it were *outside* `Variables` section, you could also use:

```
${customers}=    Create List
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! Nevertheless there is a warning in RED 'declared without assignment'. So it seems not the way intended by Robot .. ?

Comment: It says what it says: RED doesn't like it. But it doesn't mean it's a problem for Robot Framework.